# Python output on a separate lines

Tags: python

I have a simple question about Python.
I wrote a working script but when I execute it, it gives me an answer in one line, as a string.
What I am looking is an answer to be on two separate lines.
Here is a code:
      [Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt9Gy.png)

```
def test():
    fh=open('xxxxxxx.txt', 'r')
    fo=open('output.txt', 'a')
    for line in fh:
            line=line.strip()
            if(line.startswith('Total Sequences')):
                 fo.write(line)
    fh.close()
fh2=open('xxxxxxx.txt', 'r')
fo2=open('output.txt', 'a')
for line in fh2:
            line=line.strip()
            if(line.startswith('Sequence length')):
                 fo2.write(line)
fh2.close()
print(test())
```

Comment: Please add the code as text in your answer, so we can easily copy-and-paste it to test it. Also, which version of Python are you using? Printing differes between versions 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Rory, sorry, but to be honest I am not sure what exactly version of Python this is.

Comment: type python in your terminal and report back what version it shows.  Also post your output in your question, and what you want it to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing the newline characters "\n" from each line in the file with the statement:-

**line=line.strip()**

Just remove it and it should work correctly.